# Using python to add unordered list tags to plain text file (for html output)

Tags: python

I need to add unordered list tags around a long list of items using regular expressions if possible. This text is being pulled from a text file and processed inside a markup function which includes many different regex's to replace certain elements of the original text file with markup tags.

```
* Item One
* Item Two
* Item Three
* Item Four
```

I currently have a regex function to to replace the asterix with the list tags like follows.

```
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
```

How would I add in the  tags at the beginning and ending of the list using a regex or recursive/looping process? Would I be better off doing this before or after swapping the asterix for list tags?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use an existing markup solution such as reStructuredText or Markdown?

Comment: Can this block of asterisked items appear within other markup?  I'm guessing so.  In which case that makes it rather more complicated!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('*'):
            print '<li>' + line[2:] + '</li>'
```

Comment: A pity about the line `*the cat sat on the mat`... `<li>he cat sat on the mat</li>` (you might want `line[1:]` or `line[1:].lstrip()` or `if line.startswith('* '):`)

Comment: That doesn't add the `ul` tags the OP was asking for

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: '<ul>' + ''.join(['<li>'+l[2:]+'</li>' for l in open('foo.txt') if l.startswith('*')]) + '</ul>'
Out[1]: '<ul><li>Item One\n</li><li>Item Two\n</li><li>Item Three\n</li><li>Item Four\n</li></ul>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with `lxml`

```
from lxml.builder import E
from lxml import etree

items = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']
ul = E.ul()
for item in items:
    ul.append(E.li(item))
print etree.tostring(ul, pretty_print=True)
```

The above code will output:

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you already removed the `*` and added the elements to a list:

```
items = ["Item One", "Item Two", "Item Three", "Item Four"]
```

You could now:

```
html_items = '<ul>\n<li>' + '</li>\n<li>'.join(items) + '</li></ul>'
print html_items
```

Output:

```
<ul>
<li>Item One</li>
<li>Item Two</li>
<li>Item Three</li>
<li>Item Four</li>
</ul>
```